# How to reduce code duplication for class properties (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, class, properties, swift3

In my application I want to implement separate class to keep all the temporary variables of Now Playing item for Music Player.
It has lots of properties with different types, but they should be handled in the same way. They should be handled in the class method "updateData" (see the end of code)

This is my code:

```
struct DataDefaults {
    //MARK: Default properties
    let albumTitle: String? = "Unknown Album"
    let albumArtist: String? = "Unknown Artist"
    let title: String? = "Unknown Title"
    let artist: String? = "Unknown Artist"
    let artwork: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "noartwork")!
    let genre: String? = ""
    let lyrics: String? = "No Lyrics"
    let releaseDate: Date? = nil
    let playbackDuration: TimeInterval? = 0
    let rating: Int? = 0
    let assetURL: URL? = nil
    let isExplicitItem: Bool? = false
    let isCloudItem: Bool? = false
    let hasProtectedAsset: Bool? = false
}

class SongInfo: NSObject {

    static let sharedData = SongInfo()

    let defaults = DataDefaults()

    //MARK: Properties
    var albumTitle: String
    var albumArtist: String
    var title: String
    var artist: String
    var artwork: UIImage
    var genre: String
    var lyrics: String
    var releaseDate: Date?
    var playbackDuration: TimeInterval
    var rating: Int
    var assetURL: URL?
    var isExplicitItem: Bool
    var isCloudItem: Bool
    var hasProtectedAsset: Bool


    //MARK: Init
    private override init () {
        self.albumTitle = defaults.albumTitle!
        self.albumArtist = defaults.albumArtist!
        self.title = defaults.title!
        self.artist = defaults.artist!
        self.artwork = defaults.artwork!
        self.genre = defaults.genre!
        self.lyrics = defaults.lyrics!
        self.releaseDate = defaults.releaseDate
        self.playbackDuration = defaults.playbackDuration!
        self.rating = defaults.rating!
        self.assetURL = defaults.assetURL
        self.isExplicitItem = defaults.isExplicitItem!
        self.isCloudItem = defaults.isCloudItem!
        self.hasProtectedAsset = defaults.hasProtectedAsset!
    }

    //MARK: Set properties
    func updateData(allData: DataDefaults) {
        var wasUpdated: Bool = false

        if allData.albumTitle == self.albumTitle {
            //pass
        } else if allData.albumTitle == nil || allData.albumTitle == "" {
            self.albumTitle = defaults.albumTitle!
            wasUpdated = true
        } else {
            self.albumTitle = allData.albumTitle!
            wasUpdated = true
        }

        //Need to repeat same IF for all properties
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can use property name to make some reusage of the same code instead of duplicating it?

Comment: What is the purpose of **optional** non-nil constants in the `DataDefaults` struct, since they will never change the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to find a solution to a weird design, I re-designed for what you're trying to accomplish

```
struct SongData: Equatable {

    static let defaultData = SongData(albumTitle: "Unknown Album",
                                      albumArtist: "Unknown Artist",
                                      title: "Unknown Title",
                                      artist: "Unknown Artist",
                                      artwork: UIImage(named: "noartwork"),
                                      genre:"",
                                      lyrics: "No Lyrics",
                                      releaseDate: nil,
                                      playbackDuration: 0,
                                      rating: 0,
                                      assetURL: nil,
                                      isExplicitItem: false,
                                      isCloudItem: false,
                                      hasProtectedAsset: false)

    //MARK: Default properties
    var albumTitle: String?
    var albumArtist: String?
    var title: String?
    var artist: String?
    var artwork: UIImage?
    var genre: String?
    var lyrics: String?
    var releaseDate: Date?
    var playbackDuration: TimeInterval?
    var rating: Int?
    var assetURL: URL?
    var isExplicitItem: Bool?
    var isCloudItem: Bool?
    var hasProtectedAsset: Bool?

    /// This initializer will set the properties to the defaultData properties if a passed value is nil
    init(albumTitle: String?, albumArtist: String?, title: String?, artist: String?, artwork: UIImage?, genre: String?, lyrics: String?, releaseDate: Date?, playbackDuration: TimeInterval?, rating: Int?, assetURL: URL?, isExplicitItem: Bool?, isCloudItem: Bool?, hasProtectedAsset: Bool?) {

        // initialize properties where the default is nil
        self.releaseDate = releaseDate
        self.assetURL = assetURL

        //initialize other properties with the passed values, or use the default value if nil
        self.albumTitle = SongData.valueOrDefault(albumTitle, SongData.defaultData.albumTitle)
        self.albumArtist = SongData.valueOrDefault(albumArtist, SongData.defaultData.albumArtist)
        self.title = SongData.valueOrDefault(title, SongData.defaultData.title)
        self.artist = SongData.valueOrDefault(artist, SongData.defaultData.artist)
        self.artwork = artwork ?? SongData.defaultData.artwork
        self.genre = SongData.valueOrDefault(genre, SongData.defaultData.genre)
        self.lyrics = SongData.valueOrDefault(lyrics, SongData.defaultData.lyrics)
        self.playbackDuration = playbackDuration ?? SongData.defaultData.playbackDuration
        self.rating = rating ?? SongData.defaultData.rating
        self.isExplicitItem = isExplicitItem ?? SongData.defaultData.isExplicitItem
        self.isCloudItem = isCloudItem ?? SongData.defaultData.isCloudItem
        self.hasProtectedAsset = hasProtectedAsset ?? SongData.defaultData.hasProtectedAsset
    }

    static func ==(leftItem: SongData, rightItem: SongData) -> Bool {
        return  (leftItem.albumTitle == rightItem.albumTitle) &&
                (leftItem.albumArtist == rightItem.albumArtist) &&
                (leftItem.title == rightItem.title) &&

                // Comparing a reference type here. may need to be handled differently if that's a problem
                (leftItem.artwork === rightItem.artwork) &&
                (leftItem.genre == rightItem.genre) &&
                (leftItem.lyrics == rightItem.lyrics) &&
                (leftItem.releaseDate == rightItem.releaseDate) &&
                (leftItem.playbackDuration == rightItem.playbackDuration) &&
                (leftItem.rating == rightItem.rating) &&
                (leftItem.assetURL == rightItem.assetURL) &&
                (leftItem.isExplicitItem == rightItem.isExplicitItem) &&
                (leftItem.isCloudItem == rightItem.isCloudItem) &&
                (leftItem.hasProtectedAsset == rightItem.hasProtectedAsset)
    }

    //simple helper function to avoid long turneries in the init
    static func valueOrDefault(_ value: String?, _ defaultValue: String?) -> String? {
        guard let value = value, !value.isEmpty else {
            return defaultValue
        }
        return value
    }
}

class SongInfo {

    static let sharedData = SongInfo()

    var data: SongData

    //MARK: Init
    private init ()
    {
        self.data = SongData.defaultData
    }

    //MARK: Set properties
    func updateData(newData: SongData) {
        if(newData != self.data) {
            self.data = newData
        }
    }
}
```

I changed your struct to act more like it appears you're wanting it to be used, and the struct's init will fall back to using the default values if the init values are nil. My design also contains no force unwraps, which are almost always bad.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks, this is definitely what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: In this code there is a problem with initializing `defaultData`. It tries to reference itself when calls `valueOrDefault` method and drops into infinite loop. As a workaround I've used switch instead of `return defaultData`:         `switch defaultValue {
 case "albumTitle":
        return "Unknown Album"
 ...}`

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I was trying to avoid 2 initializers, but you probably want to have a separate initializer for the default value that simply sets the values.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the defaults directly in your class definition without using a separate struct and have a static unaltered instance with the default values.

For example:

```
class SongInfo: NSObject {

    static let sharedData = SongInfo()

    static let defaults   = SongInfo()

    //MARK: Properties
    var albumTitle: String?      = "Unknown Album"
    var albumArtist: String?     = "Unknown Artist"
    var title: String?           = "Unknown Title"
    var artist: String?          = "Unknown Artist"
    var artwork: UIImage?        = UIImage(named: "noartwork")!
    var genre: String?           = ""
    var lyrics: String?          = "No Lyrics"
    var releaseDate: Date?       = nil
    var playbackDuration: TimeInterval? = 0
    var rating: Int?             = 0
    var assetURL: URL?           = nil
    var isExplicitItem: Bool?    = false
    var isCloudItem: Bool?       = false
    var hasProtectedAsset: Bool? = false


    //MARK: Init
    private override init () 
    {
       // nothing to do here
    }

    //MARK: Set properties
    func updateData(allData: DataDefaults) {
        var wasUpdated: Bool = false

        if allData.albumTitle == self.albumTitle {
            //pass
        } else if allData.albumTitle == nil || allData.albumTitle == "" {
            self.albumTitle = SongInfo.defaults.albumTitle!
            wasUpdated = true
        } else {
            self.albumTitle = allData.albumTitle!
            wasUpdated = true
        }

        //Need to repeat same IF for all properties
    }
}
```

If you also need to manipulate the basic data without the whole class functionality, you could define a SongInfoData class with only the properties and make SingInfo inherit from that class.  Then the static variable for defaults could be in the SongInfoData class and the SingInfo subclass wouldn't need any property declarations.

[EDIT] avoiding code repetition in update function ...

You can generalize the property update process by adding a generic function to your class:

For example:

```
func assign<T:Equatable>(_ variable:inout T?, _ getValue:(SongInfo)->T?) -> Int
{
     let newValue = getValue(self) 

     if variable == newValue 
     { return 0 }

     var valueIsEmpty = false
     if let stringValue = newValue as? String, stringValue == ""
     { valueIsEmpty = true }

     if newValue == nil || valueIsEmpty
     { 
       variable = getValue(SongInfo.defaults)
       return 1
     }

     variable = newValue
     return 1              
}

func update(with newInfo:SongInfo)
{
   let updates = newInfo.assign(&albumTitle)  {$0.albumTitle}
               + newInfo.assign(&albumArtist) {$0.albumArtist}
               + newInfo.assign(&title)       {$0.title}
               + newInfo.assign(&artist)      {$0.artist}
               + newInfo.assign(&artwork)     {$0.artwork}
               + newInfo.assign(&genre)       {$0.genre}
               + newInfo.assign(&lyrics)      {$0.lyrics}
               // ...

   if updates > 0
   {
     // react to update
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's an interesting point and I will consider it. But my question was regarding the `updateData` method. First of all, I expect it to receive same properties that I'm using in the struct, that why I define it separately. The actual question is can I somehow not copy-pasting IF statement in `updateData` method for each property?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you're using `MPMedia` item.
If so, you don't have to store all these properties at all.
You just need to store persistent ID of the item (convert from UInt64 to string), and later fetch `MPMediaItem` by using `MPMediaQuery` with predicate, something like this:

```
func findSong(persistentIDString: String) -> MPMediaItem? {
    let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: persistentIDString, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID)
    let songQuery = MPMediaQuery()
    songQuery.addFilterPredicate(predicate)

    return songQuery.items.first
}
```

Comment: yes, I use `MPMediaItem`, but I want to separate any MediaPlayer intercations from the DataStorage. I want DataStorage to be re-written from separate MediaPlayer class